# Strange message with servlets

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am using eclipse with tomcat here is my servlet ,the problem is when I click the button called GetStared it redirects me to empty html page with the text "surved at :myproject123" . myproject123 is the name of my project in the eclipse IDE.

```
@WebServlet("/home")
public class homeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String htmlFile = "loginPage.html";
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(htmlFile);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Here is my html file : called index.html

```
<div class="background-wrap">
    <video id="video-bg-elem"
           preload="auto"
           autoplay="autoplay"
           loop="loop" muted="muted">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Video not supported
    </video>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="vertical_align">
            <h2>Spotify</h2>
            <output>Music for each moment.</output>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical_align2">
            <form action="home" method="GET">
                <button type="submit"
                        value="Get Started"
                        class="animated_button">
                    GET STARTED
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is loginPage.html

```
        <div class="myCirle">

            <img src="logo10.png" />
            <div class="under_logo">
                <p>Spotify.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form-signin" action="login" method="POST"> 
             <div class="form-input" > 
                <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder = "Enter username" />
            </div >
            <div class="form-input" > 
            <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter password" /> 
            </div >
            <div class="form-input">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn-login" /><br />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In With Facebook" class="btn-loginFB" />
            </div>
             <div class="form-input">
             <a href="#"> Forgot password?</a>
             </div>
             <div class="form-input">
                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Not a spotifyier yet?" class="btn-reg" />
             </div>
             </form>
         </div> 
</body >
```

Comment: what is the name of the html page?

Comment: index.html and wants to redirect to loginPage.html

Comment: Do you know where `surved at` text is?

Comment: I haven't type "surved at" anywhere.It appears like a plain text so I guess it is somekind of error ?

Comment: Can you post the content of your loginPage.html. On the top of that What I don't understand is why are you forwarding the request and response object into static page. you probably need jsp page to access your request and response object[this part is nothing to do with your issue]

Comment: What can I use instead of forwarding and I don't have web.xml file in my project is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

problem seems to be with forward the request....you can try this.. `request.getRequestDispatcher("/"+htmlFile); or request.getRequestDispatcher("//"+htmlFile);`

it is so because getRequestDispatcher () accepts link to the resources instead of direct file name.So if your file in inside your webapp like MyApp/myFile,then

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/myFile");
```

if it is inside **WEB-INF**,then..

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/myFile");
```

and so on...